# How to start an app the same way Android Launcher does (resume)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launcher

There are a lot of questions/answers about how to start an application from within your application in Android. But those solutions do not produce the same flow as if an icon was tapped in Android launcher.
For example, I do this (this is used with notifications):

```
intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.test.startup");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then when I tap on notification the app is started, however, it is started somewhat differently than when I tap the icon in the App drawer. Specifically: with this approach my main Activity is *always* created (i.e. onCreate() then onResume() is called). However, if application was already started and then put in background, then starting it from Launcher will only cause onResume() of currently shown activity to be called (not onCreate() on the main one). Is there a way to trigger the same resume flow programmatically from within my app?

To summarize the task: when user taps on notification I need my app to be either started (if it's not already), or brought to the foreground in its current state (if it's in background)  and have some data passed to it. The app will then take care of handling/rendering that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is behaving the way it supposed to. Even if you try the launch the app from App drawer it will call the same callback. You have to understand the lifecycle. As your activity is in the background onCreate will not get called. But for the handling the data from the notification intent you should utilize callback method OnNewIntent() in activity. You should override this method and extract the data the from the new intent and should update UI. After onNewIntent onresume will be called.
I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my onPause code which works the way you expected i.e when user clicks on the notification it doesnt call onCreate again:

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerActivity.class);     
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, intent,0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder noti =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play)
                .setContentTitle("Nepali Music And more")
                .setContentText("Playing");
    noti.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    noti.setAutoCancel(true);
    noti.setOngoing(true);
     Notification notification = noti.getNotification();


        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Focus mainly on the intent flags

Comment: No, this doesn't seem to work. Aren't you starting the PlayerActivity here? In my case it seems like I don't want to start any specific Activity, but whatever there is currently running in the app (I have multiple activities and any one of them can be on the top of the stack). For that reason, I am also not sure that FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP should be a part of solution, since it basically clears the stack, which I don't want. I need the app to come back to foreground in exactly the same state as it was when "Home" was pressed.
Also, this still causes onCreate() when app is not in foreground.

Comment: Yes , this is the onPause code in PlayerActivity so it starts PlayerActivity, In onPause of another activity, I start that another activity in notification click

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the intent flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to find your activity and clear the stack above it.  You also need the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag to prevent your activity from being recreated (to resume).

The `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` is necessary since by default, the launch mode is "standard" which lets you create multiple instances of your activity.  If you were to set your launch mode to `SingleTop`, then this flag own't be necessary